# How stable is EBS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto

I'm thinking about saving data from EC2 instances to the EBS and later save the result on S3. I don't have a lot of experience working with EBS, so my questions are:

- How stable they are? I mean how often (if any) you had problem with EBS. Do they crash if overloaded or something like this?
- What are the chances of loosing data from EBS?
- Is it possible to mount one EBS to the multiple Instances? (let's say two ec2 share the same ebs )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you've read [AWS's take on EBS](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/)

1. Pretty stable. Last year, 10% of EBS volumes failed in 2-3 data centers in us-east for a couple hours. This is the only issue I've ever had with them.
2. I've never lost data from EBS. Even if I had, I take hourly snapshots (stored in s3), so I would have been just fine.
3. Not at the same time. To attach it to another instance, you must detach from the currently attached one.

Perhaps what you're look is [s3fs](https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/) - a way to mount s3 as a filesystem.

Comment: s3fs can be a bit funky. Since s3 is not a block device, adding it to the filesystem where it might be treated as one can produce unexpected results. For it to work well, you need to move files to and from an s3fs mount, be careful when opening a file directly or storing anything that will be constantly accessed (like database files)

Answer (score 1):

EBS is quite stable and every data you write is redundantly copied in 3 disks inside a AZ. If you take regular snapshots of your EBS volumes you can protect your data more. Since EBS operate in AZ scope it is recommended to moves assets like user documents, images, videos to Amazon S3. S3 offer more redundancy and availability than an EBS Volume.

You cannot mount single EBS volume to Multiple EC2 instances. You will have to use Solution like GlusterFS on AWS so that multiple EC2 instances can talk to common storage pool.